# Searching for a date in a text file

Tags: python

Please can someone help me tidy up this piece of code as I'm new to python and I don't think i have written it in the most efficient way:

```
elif choice == "2":
    birthday = input("Which birthday month do you require?e.g.  /10/ : ")
    for line in searchfile:
        if birthday in line:
           print (line)
searchfile.close
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You should post here if you want a review.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a code review. As such it is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thank you, I didn't realise but in future I will post this kind of thing there.

Answer (score 1):

Three tips:

Generally it is safer to use `raw_input` instead of `input` since the latter evaluates the input before passing it to your code and therefore allows execution of arbitrary code.

If '10' is in the file, then so is '1', so if someone searched for January ('1'), they would find January, October, November, and December birthdays. Maybe you could spell out the birth month in your data file?

If you're only opening searchfile to read the birthday data, wait until you are inside the `if` statement to open it, and then open it with a `with` statement to invisibly close it.

I would write your code in the following way:

```
elif choice == '2':
    birthday = raw_input("Which birthday month do you require? e.g. January: ")
    for line in searchfile:
        if birthday in line:
            print(line)
    searchfile.close()
```

NB: The `print(line)` works in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

Comment: You might be able to use '1' as a birth month, if you check in that case that '10', '11', and '12' are not in the line, but this depends on what else is in that line (e.g. it won't work if you have days of the month).

Comment: Thank you, to make it less confusing I renamed the months in the text file to words not numbers and it is now a lot tidier and easier to use.